# How to make dovecot and postfix use the same mail directory

Tags: postfix, ldap, dovecot, imap

I'm trying to configure postfix and dovecot to connect to the same LDAP, and I kind of succeeded. But now, I have some discrepencies.

The reproduction is as:

- I connect to dovecot in IMAP with thunderbird
- I create an email from myself to send to myself
- I use the postfix from the same server with the same user
- I send the email

The results are:

- The sent email is put in the Sent folder.
- But I get no email in my inbox.

Checking on the server:

- The sent email is in the `/var/mail/<username>/.Sent/cur/` directory
- The received email is in the `/var/mail/<domain>/<username>/new/` directory

I thought I configured the maildir directory both the same way (as in `/var/mail/%d/%n`), but there must be a problem.

[My configuration](https://gist.github.com/dolanor/c970012cf09e684ace019f80ef2c5cd3) (external, sorry, couldn't make it in the question. And after 30h (still counting) on those damn configuration files, I'm not really sure which part might impact what…)

Answer (score 1):

Do not deliver messages by postfix. Pass them to the dovecot's `deliver` instead.

See https://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix for further information.

Comment: It's already the case, it uses dovecot-lmtp.
But still, it's in the wrong directory, and I don't see, based on my configuration, why it is.

Answer (score 1):

Keep `home_mailbox =` in the main.cf empty, and

`smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot`

`smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth`

and in dovecot conf

`mail_home = /var/mail/%d/%n`

`mail_location = maildir:~`

Also in dovecot conf you need to add or change this:

```
service auth {

    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth { 
        mode = 0666
        #Change to the user and group of your postfix
        user = postfix  
        group = postfix
    }

    unix_listener auth-userdb {
        mode = 0666
        #Change to the user and group of your postfix
        user = postfix
        group = postfix
    }
    #dovecot user
    user = dovecot

}


service auth-worker {
  # Auth worker process is run as root by default, so that it can access
  # /etc/shadow. If this isn't necessary, the user should be changed to
  # $default_internal_user.
  user = root
}
```